# Defer() Queryset in Django is not working

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to do a queryset request to my database that I would like to exclude a entire column from the response, in this case the column weigth. But the response is returning all columns from the database. I am trying to use defer but it is not working.

What I am doing wrong?

Views.py

```
def product_table(request):
   width = request.GET['width']
   length = request.GET['length']
   prod_filter = Product.objects.filter(length=length,width=width).defer('weigth')
   data_prod =serializers.serialize('json', prod_filter)
   return JsonResponse({'data_prod':data_prod})
```

Html

```
    ... 
    <div>
        <table id="id_prod" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          ...
                $.get('{% url "prod_table" %}',function (data_prod) {
                    var data_json = JSON.parse(data_prod['data_prod']);
                    var data_array = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < data_json.length; i++) {
                        var arr = $.map(data_json[i]['fields'], function(el) { return el });
                        data_array.push(arr);
                    }


                    $('#id_prod').DataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        data: data_array,
                        columns: [
                            { title: "Name" },
                            { title: "width" },
                            { title: "length" },
                            { title: "volume" },

                        ]
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Note you have misspelled `weight`

Comment: ok.. will correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alasdair said, you need to tell your seralizer to not return fields you don't want. Just using `defer()` simply tells Django to wait on loading that column from the database until you use it. So if the serializer tries to serialize the value of that field, it will be read. `defer()` doesn't block you from using that field, it just defers its retrieval.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer):

> A queryset that has deferred fields will still return model instances.
>   Each deferred field will be retrieved from the database if you access
>   that field (one at a time, not all the deferred fields at once).

Answer (score 5):

Your [`defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) call prevents Django from loading the column when it fetches the queryset. However your serializer then needs the value of the deferred field, so fetches the value later. This means you actually end up doing more queries that if you hadn't used defer at all!

If you only want to [serialize a subset of the fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields), then you need to specify `fields` when you serialize the queryset:

```
data_prod =serializers.serialize('json', prod_filter, fields=['width', 'length', ...)
```

Note that in practice, the `.defer('weight')` optimisation is probably not necessary. In practice you may not see any noticeable decrease in query time.

Comment: Hi Alasdair.. thanks for the repply, but How can I include a argumet in the serialization that could eliminate duplicity, like distinct in queryset filter?

Comment: If I apply the distinct in the queryset and after I serialize. I will keep the duplicity rigth? How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This sounds like a different issue than your original question.